# Executing a jquery function or bypass jquery countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, console

There is a countdown in a page. And i want to bypass or speed it up. 
Is there a possibility to run add ticket function from chrome's console or something?Or can I change the xtime variable to something like 2-3 seconds.Or directly call the add ticket function?

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var xTime=120;
    $("#ticketTimer").html(xTime);
    var myVar = setInterval( 
    function(){
        if(typeof checkAdBlock === 'undefined') 
        {
             document.getElementById("compt").innerHTML = "<b>you use an AdBlocker!</b> To win a ticket, <b>Desactivate AdBlock and reload the page.</b>";

            return false;
        }
        else if(xTime>0)
        {
            xTime--;
            $("#ticketTimer").html(xTime);
        }
        else
        {
            addTicket();
            clearInterval(myVar);

        }
    },
    1000);
    });
```

Comment: looks like you might be able to run `addTicket();` from the console ... but won't be able to change `xtime` from console as it is a closure variable

Comment: When i wrote addTicket(); to the console: it returns me undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: if it is just returning `undefined` then it is executing the method - unless an error is thrown

Comment: Thanks for helping. Looks like calling the function does not do the trick that i wanted unfortunately.